# pygame audio error Unrecognized audio format

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

I am using pygame 2.0.0 python 3.8.2 and ubuntu 20 to open audio files but I still get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aryan/Desktop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
pygame.error: Unrecognized audio format
```

the song.mp3 file and the code are in same directory and here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello')


pygame.mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()

while True: # Main Loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

does anyone know what should I do to fix this error

some searches lead me that pygame 1.9.6 is ok with audio file is there a way to downgrade my pygame from 2.0.0 to 1.9.6?
thank you for answers

Comment: Pygame.mixer will not load .MP3 files, because of licensing restrictions. Your code needs to use PyGame.music() - https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html  Or you can convert them to .OGG (or .wav, or whatever).  I think the MP3 patent has expired now, so maybe one-day it will work again.

Comment: Same issue here with Debian 10. @Kingsley `pygame.mixer.music` doesn't solve the problem. Had to downgrade

Answer (score 2):

A better way for playing `.mp3` song in pygame is by converting them into `.ogg` or `.wav`. Is there any way doing it locally in the code ? Yes, it sure is.
You have to `pip install pydub`.

Using pydub import `AudioSegment`, then convert mp3 to ogg file.

Example:

```py
AudioSegment.from_mp3("mymp3.mp3").export('myogg.ogg', format='ogg')
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

simple and easy solution ,convert mp3 file into ogg format and then pass (ogg file into above func).it will definitely work.

Comment: An example code for your solution would surely increase the quality of this answer, consider addidng it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pygame.mixer.sound(filename)`:

```py
my_song = pygame.mixer.sound(os.path.join(IMG_FOLDER, 'song.mp3'))
my_song.play()
```

Then you could use is pre-initialising the  ‘pygame.mixer’ making:

```
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize
pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on. This is the line where you wrote pygame.init()
```

Pre-init the mixer before everything initialising everything else. Use this in combination with this first method.

Here is what the documentation says:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound

> Load a new sound buffer from a filename, a python file object or a readable buffer object.

**If you wish to install a different version of pygame use the following steps:**

1. `pip3 uninstall pygame`
2. `pip3 install "pygame==1.9.6"`  # Will install version '1.9.6'

This will make sure the version you want is installed.

Comment: I tried .sound and I got this new error instead:
my_song = pygame.mixer.Sound('song.mp3')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'song.mp3'

Comment: @aryanesmailpour Try the new method I just added and if that does not work then I will delete my answer.

Comment: still same result with the new method

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the version you asked for?

Comment: I know it seems weird but every other versions of pygame that I tried to install I got this error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
so the only version that I can use is pygame 2.0.0.dev6
I searched for this problem too and the only answer was to use pygame 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install brew, if you already have brew installed, skip to step 2. Install brew here for Linux: https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-homebrew-on-linux-or-wsl.html

Step 2: Open a terminal and type these commands, pressing enter after each one:

```
brew deinstall all
```

```
brew install hg sdl etc
```

```
compile sdl_mixer
```

```
pip3 install pygame
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I migrated a similar PyCharm project from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 and it did not reproduce the sound, I only changed the Python interpreter from 3.9 to 3.8 and it worked very well it reproduces all audio formats, it is worth mentioning that the original project had python 3.9 as the one Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for this is to use **audioplayer** package. It provides all functionality of pygame and it support .mp3, .ogg etc formats.

```py
from audioplayer import AudioPlayer

player = AudioPlayer("demo.mp3")

player.play()

player.stop() 

player.pause()
player.unpause()
```